# How to add create a string var from integer and string?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and just analyzing the syntax..

How do I display "1text" here?

```
$a = 1;
$b = 'text';
$c = $a + $b;

echo $c;
```

Comment: In PHP, you use `.` for concatenation. So, it'd be: `$c = $a.$b;` - but please read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and have a look at similar questions before asking a new question.

Comment: You can also use `$c = "$a$b"` (This is different from concatenation, in that PHP simply replaces `$a` and `$b` in the string with their values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP `.` is the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for strings:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 'text';
$c = $a . $b;

echo $c;
```

Comment: Wasn't me buddy, I put it back to 0 from -1